# Are all the shell options not inherited by scripts?

Tags: bash

If I run `set -x`  and then run a script in a shell, the option set by `set -x` doesn't work inside the script.

I was wondering  if all the shell options are not inherited by scripts?

I didn't find this is mentioned in bash manual. The only relevant that I found is "Unless otherwise noted, the values are inherited from the shell." So I guess shell options are inherited. Do I miss it in the manual?

I have read [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17852801/156458) which asked how to let scripts inherit shell options. I was wondering whether and why instead of how.

Thanks.

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be
>   executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that
>   consists of the following. **Unless otherwise noted, the values are
>   inherited from the shell.**
>
> • the shell’s open files, plus any modifications and additions
>   specified by redirections to the command
>
> • the current working directory
>
> • the fi le creation mode mask
>
> • shell variables and functions marked for export, along with
>   variables exported for the command, passed in the environment (see
>   Section 3.7.4 [Environment], page 37)
>
> • traps caught by the shell are reset to the values inherited from the
>   shell’s parent, and traps ignored by the shell are ignored A command
>   invoked in this separate environment cannot aff ect the shell’s
>   execution environment.

Comment: No shell options are inherited. There's no readily available underlying mechanism that could facilitate such inheritance (well `export -` could be made to provide that through an environment variable, but I'm not aware of any shell that implements that. I also don't think implementing it would be a good idea).

Comment: @PSkocik, in `bash`, you can have options inherited with the `$SHELLOPTS` (for the `set -o` ones) and `$BASHOPTS` (for the `shopt` ones). Try `env SHELLOPTS= bash -xc 'bash -c :'` and see how the second `bash` inherited the `xtrace` option set by the first one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good to know. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of `bash`, that depends on whether `$SHELLOPTS` is in the environment or not.

```
bash-4.4$ export SHELLOPTS
bash-4.4$ set -x
bash-4.4$ bash -c 'echo x'
+ bash -c 'echo x'
+ echo x
x
```

See how the `bash -c 'echo x'` inherited the `xtrace` option. For the options set by `shopt`, it's the same but with the `$BASHOPTS` variable.

It comes handy especially for the `xtrace` option for debugging when you want to run a `bash` script (or any command running a `bash` script) and all other `bash` script it may invoke, recursively with `xtrace` (provided nothing does a `set +x` in those scripts). If your `sh` is `bash`, that will also affect them, so also the `system("command line")` made in other languages:

```
env SHELLOPTS=xtrace some-command
```

Answer (score 4):

You could call scripts (or a shell with a command line) explicitly with options:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias shell_call='bash -$-'
shell_call /path/to/script
```

Changes to the script would automatically be passed to child shells. This approch does only turn features on, though.

Comment: You mean `bash -$-` so you're passing the options as options instead of attempting to run a file named "$-"

Comment: Thanks, Hauke! I wonder if I misunderstand the manual? It doesn't explicitly mention set options, so I think "Unless otherwise noted, the values are inherited from the shell" applies to set options. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tim I guess your misunderstanding is "execution environment". The environment is external to a running binary, the shell options are internal. This paragraph is about simple commands in general. Calling a shell explicitly is a very special case.